# Getting error while asigning a tuple in Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a tuple inside a `__init__(self)` method but it is showing  `ValueError: Accel.x must have 2 components (got (0, 0, 0, 0, 0))`

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from plyer import accelerometer
from kivy.uix .relativelayout import RelativeLayout
Builder.load_string("""
<Accel>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical' 
        Label:
            id: x_val
            text: 'X:'
        Label:
            id: y_val
            text: 'y:'
        Label:
            id: z_val
            text: 'z:'

        Label:
            id: x_tst
            text: 'value:'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        padding: '4dp'

        ToggleButton:
            id: start_btn
            text: 'Start accelerometer'
            on_press: root.accelerometer()
""")

class Accel(RelativeLayout):


    def __init__(self):
        super(Accel, self).__init__()
        self.sensorEnabled=False
        self.counter=0
        self.x=(0,0,0,0,0)

    def accelerometer(self):


        if not self.sensorEnabled:
            accelerometer.enable()
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.accelerate, 1/5)
            self.sensorEnabled =True
            self.ids.start_btn.text="Stop"
        else:
            accelerometer.disable()
            Clock.unschedule(self.accelerate)
            self.sensorEnabled =False
            self.ids.start_btn.text = "Start"

    def accelerate(self,dt):
        print(self.x)
        val=accelerometer.acceleration[:3]


        if not val==(None,None,None):
            self.ids.x_val.text="X:" +str(val[0])
            self.ids.y_val.text="y:" +str(val[1])
            self.ids.z_val.text="z:" +str(val[2])




class MeterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Accel()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MeterApp().run()
```

When I run it it shows:

```
File "/root/PycharmProjects/Chat/accelerometer.py", line 73, in build
     return Accel()
   File "/root/PycharmProjects/Chat/accelerometer.py", line 42, in __init__
     self.x=(0,0,0,0,0)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (/tmp/pip-build-0vou9szt/kivy/kivy/properties.c:5572)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 498, in kivy.properties.Property.set (/tmp/pip-build-0vou9szt/kivy/kivy/properties.c:6091)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 625, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert (/tmp/pip-build-0vou9szt/kivy/kivy/properties.c:7891)
 ValueError: Accel.x must have 2 components (got (0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: when i try adding self.x=[0,0,0,0,0] it shows me the same error

Comment: Please try to keep chat to a minimum in questions, especially in titles - "here is the code" and "take a look" are quite redundant there.

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to a minimum? It seems like there's a lot of stuff in there that's totally unrelated to your question.  Also, the error seems to tell you that `Accel.x` should only have 2 components (e.g., `(0, 0)`), not 5 as you're passing.

Comment: @Elmar Peise Thankyou

Comment: @halfer i will not repeat that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You getting an error because `self.x` is already a position attribute of `RelativeLayout` and is of type `int`. So your going to need to name your tuple something else.

Edit:

Just to show you, `print(dir(self))` and you get ('x' is at the end) :

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__events__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__',
'__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__proxy_getter', '__proxy_setter', '__pyx_vtable__', '__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_apply_transform', 
'_context', '_kwargs_applied_init', '_proxy_ref', '_trigger_layout', '_walk', '_walk_reverse', 'accelerate', 
'accelerometer', 'add_widget', 'apply_property', 'bind', 'canvas', 'center', 'center_x', 'center_y', 'children', 
'clear_widgets', 'cls', 'collide_point', 'collide_widget', 'counter', 'create_property', 'disabled', 'dispatch', 
'dispatch_children', 'dispatch_generic', 'do_layout', 'events', 'export_to_png', 'fbind', 'funbind', 'get_center_x', 
'get_center_y', 'get_parent_window', 'get_property_observers', 'get_right', 'get_root_window', 'get_top', 
'get_window_matrix', 'getter', 'height', 'id', 'ids', 'is_event_type', 'layout_hint_with_bounds', 'on_disabled', 
'on_opacity', 'on_touch_down', 'on_touch_move', 'on_touch_up', 'opacity', 'parent', 'pos', 'pos_hint', 'properties', 
'property', 'proxy_ref', 'register_event_type', 'remove_widget', 'right', 'sensorEnabled', 'set_center_x', 'set_center_y', 
'set_right', 'set_top', 'setter', 'size', 'size_hint', 'size_hint_max', 'size_hint_max_x', 'size_hint_max_y', 
'size_hint_min', 'size_hint_min_x', 'size_hint_min_y', 'size_hint_x', 'size_hint_y', 'to_local', 'to_parent', 'to_widget', 
'to_window', 'top', 'uid', 'unbind', 'unbind_uid', 'unregister_event_types', 'walk', 'walk_reverse', 'width', 'x', 'y']
```